# Using section sign (§) for cross-references to sections

Tags: symbols, cross-referencing, formatting

In some papers and books you see that author uses **§1.3** instead of **section 1.3**. How § sign can be added before section (or part, chapter, ...) number automatically? Please mention any useful tip about this style.

**see also:** [Fancy cross-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59938/13747)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use the [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and redefine `\crefname{section}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{section}{§}{§§}
\Crefname{section}{§}{§§}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}\label{sec:foo}

Some text.

\section{bar}

As explained in \cref{sec:foo}~\dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 you can avoid `inputenc` by using `\S`

Comment: @lockstep Little late to the party here, but can the space after § be removed?

Comment: @jstephenson Use `\crefformat{section}{§#2#1#3}`.

Answer (score 28):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides `\autoref{<label>}` that checks the counter used in the reference and sets a label with a prepended `\<counter>autorefname`. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
See~\autoref{another-section}.
\section{Another section}\label{another-section}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: What I have done is the past is also redefined `\subsectionautorefname` and `\subsubsectionautorefname` to be the same as `\sectionautorefname` so that you can get "See § 2.1" or "See § 3.2.1". If one also uses `autopageref`, one can also redefine `\pageautorefname` to "p." to get "See § 3.2 on p. 4"

Comment: To avoid the space, use:
`\def\Snospace~{\S{}}`, then `\renewcommand*\sectionautorefname{\Snospace}` instead.
```

Answer (score 14):

Often forgotten is the macro `\p@<counter>`. If LaTeX generates a reference value, this is
not just `\the<counter>` but `\p@<counter>\the<counter>`. If a new counter is defined,
`\p@<counter>` is defined empty. But it can be redefined to add a prefix, for example.
Thus there is no need for additional packages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\S\,}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\S\,}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Hello World}
\label{sec:hello}
\subsection{Subsection A}
\subsection{Subsection B}
\subsection{Subsection C}
\label{sec:C}

See \ref{sec:C} inside \ref{sec:hello}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should that be `\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\S\S\,}` instead?

Comment: The double form of the section sign is used, if it refers to the plural form.

Answer (score 8):

I spent a little time figuring the solution for me so I thought I'd share. In case, like me:

- You don't want to use the package `cleveref` (cf [lockstep's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59890/35477)) because it is incompatible with the `showonlyrefs` option of the package `mathtools`
- You would rather not do [Heiko Oberdiek's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66120/35477) because you'd like to maintain the distinction between `\ref` and `\autoref`
- You like the `hyperref` package and [Werner's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59891/35477) but it does not work because you are using the package babel

Here is the fix, found [here](https://te35477x.stackexchange.com/a/94874/):

```
\addto\extrasenglish{
  \def\sectionautorefname{\S}
}
```

Here it is in a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}

\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \def\sectionautorefname{\S}%
}    

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
Cf \autoref{sec:bar}.
\section{Bar}\label{sec:bar}

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: Why does using `babel` prevent Werner's solution from working? Also what is the purpose of the `%` markers at the end of the two lines where you apply your solution?

Comment: @Anonymous `%` at the end of line is for Tex to ignore the newline when `{...}` spans multiple lines. I'm not too clear about the mechanics, but it does solve errors.