# redefining \ref command to avoid \textit

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

I (not me, an answer to [Using section sign (§) for cross-references to sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59889/2693)) have redefined the command `\ref` to be able to get the symbol `\S`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\SectionSymbol}% Add section symbol to section reference
\makeatother
```

The problem comes when I'm in an italic environment (like a theorem). Then, the numbers given by `\ref{whatever}` are italic. How can I solve  it (avoiding use `cleveref` package if it is possible)?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\S}% Add section symbol to section reference
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\P}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{A.1}
\label{a}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A.2}

\begin{remark}
\ref{a} \lipsum[2]
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What did cleveref do to you? ;o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing `\ref` is not really recommended. Change `\p@section` and `\p@subsection` rather, by gobbling `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` first and switching back to `\normalfont` within a group.

Of course, this will be tricky if there are other references to be done.

This is similar to my answer I provided [here!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397724/31729)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\makeatletter
\def\gobblesomething#1\csname thesection\endcsname{\begingroup\normalfont\S\thesection\endgroup}
\def\gobblesomethingother#1\csname thesubsection\endcsname{\begingroup\normalfont\P\thesubsection\endgroup}
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\gobblesomething}
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\gobblesomethingother}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{A.1}
\label{a}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A.2}

\begin{remark} \label{b}
See \ref{a} \lipsum[2]
\end{remark}

And what about \ref{a} or \ref{b}?
\end{document}
```

A similar question is this one: [Reference appendix objects within texts as 'A. 1', but not 'Appendix A. 1'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413002/reference-appendix-objects-within-texts-as-a-1-but-not-appendix-a-1)

Answer (score 5):

It makes sense to redefine the internal `\@setref` to always choose upshape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@setref}{\expandafter#2#1}{\textup{\expandafter#2#1}}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\S}% Add section symbol to section reference
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\P}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{b}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{A.1}
\label{a}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A.2}

\begin{remark}
See \ref{a} and \ref{b} \lipsum[2]
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If `hyperref` is needed, the patches are a bit more complicated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\makeatletter
\catcode`#=12
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\@setref}
    {\expandafter\Hy@setref@link#1\@empty\@empty\@nil{#2}}
    {\textup{\expandafter\Hy@setref@link#1\@empty\@empty\@nil{#2}}}
    {}{}%
}
\catcode`#=6
\patchcmd{\real@setref}{\expandafter#2#1}{\textup{\expandafter#2#1}}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\S}% Add section symbol to section reference
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\P}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{b}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{A.1}
\label{a}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A.2}

\begin{remark}
See \ref{a} and \ref{b} \lipsum[2]
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to remove the italics from `\ref` you can define an `\upshape` version of `\ref`, like this:

```
\let\refBKP\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{{\upshape\refBKP{#1}}}
```

Then all your `\ref` commands will no longer be italicized.

Comment: Your answer also works perfectly and I have marked it as useful. But to solve the problem with the section and subsection references I think @ChristianHupfer answer is better. I'm sorry, I had to choice one :( But thanks.

Comment: @Dog_69 No need to apologise ^-^. Christian's answer is far more clever. Mine is just a dirty trick ;)