# Reference appendix objects within texts as 'A. 1', but not 'Appendix A. 1'

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, appendices

Consider a document using [elsearticle](https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) package, and involving an appendix:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

... briefly explained in~\ref{sec:subAppendix}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Sub-appendix}
\label{sec:subAppendix}

\end{document}
```

When one refers this appendix object within the text:

```
... briefly explained in~\ref{sec:subAppendix}.
```

The number assigned to the object is printed with a word 'Appendix' as follows:

```
... briefly explained in Appendix A.1.
```

How can we suppress/remove the word '**Appendix**', and make the appendix object appears like in the following?:

```
... briefly explained in A.1.
```

Comment: This seems to be class and package dependent. Please give us a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see what causes this.

Comment: Does \thesection include Appendix?  Also check the aux file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elsarticle` defines `\thesection` as `\appendixname \Alph{section}` within `\appendix` -- as such, `\thesubsection` expands to `\appendix \Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}`, finally being `Appendix A.1` etc.

While this might alright for the typesetting, the references might become tedious and lengthy.

Redefinition of `\p@subsection` by gobbling the content first and re-injection of the pure `\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}` will remove this for the references.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397724/31729 for a similar approach.

Another possibility is to refine `\thesection` for the appendix.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\def\@gobbleappendixname#1\csname thesubsection\endcsname{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\@gobbleappendixname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



... briefly explained in~\ref{sec:subAppendix}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}

\subsection{Sub-appendix} 

\label{sec:subAppendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding the complaints of the OP:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}


\makeatletter
\def\@gobbleappendixname#1\csname thesubsection\endcsname{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\@gobbleappendixname}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\section{Foo} \label{firstsection}

\subsection{Foo subsection} \label{foosubsection}

... briefly explained in~\ref{sec:subAppendix} or in \ref{firstsection} or in \ref{firstappendixsection} or in \ref{foosubsection}

\appendix




\section{Appendix} \label{firstappendixsection}

\subsection{Sub-appendix} 

\label{sec:subAppendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course changing `\thesection` would be easier, but that will change the typesetting of section titles etc. as well...

Comment: The above code example unfortunately also changes the subsection numeration of the main text. For example, please consider `\ref{section:Methodology}` returns `3.4`. With the above code, this starts to return `C.4`. Just to let you know.

Comment: @Kuti: There is no `section:Methodology` label, to begin with ... And it does not return something like `C.4` or 3.4 -- The changes were meant to use on the appendix code only, nothing else, but I have shifted it to the `\appendix` macro ;-)