# Formatting of section reference

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

For a conference paper I have to use a custom package provided by the conference. This package contains the following line:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
```

which puts a dot after the number in a section title. Now, when I add a reference to a section, the dot is shown in the reference as well. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% real code:
% \usepackage{myconference}
% MWE code:
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\label{sec:first}
In Section~\ref{sec:first} the reference does not look good.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The style guide of the conference does not specify the appearance of section references. Therefore, I would like to remove the dot in the reference (while keeping the dot in the title itself). I am not allowed to change the conference package, but I can modify the code of my own paper, including redefining `\ref` (or using a custom command for referencing) if necessary. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of trying to remove it from the reference, you should not put it there in the first place. Perhaps follow the instructions in [How to add a dot after the section number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24439/5764)

Comment: @Marijn Look at the egreg ansver https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24444/66024

Comment: @Werner you are right, of course, but this is what the conference provides (which I cannot change).

Comment: @sergiokapone that is a nice solution but it does not work together with the redefined `\thesection` from the conference package.

Comment: @Marijn: That's fine... since you're defining your own content anyway, you can redefine it back to what it was (`\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`) and then use other packages or a manual correct of `\@seccntformat`.

Comment: @Werner that is a good idea as well! I think I prefer the black magic of Christian Hupfer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could gobble the `.` by using something like `\def\@gobbledot`, delimiting it with `\csname thesection\endcsname` and then redefine `\p@section`, which is basically responsible for the cross-reference formatting.

The approach is quite similar to my answer to [Automatically encase a cross-referenced equation number in round parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352241/automatically-encase-a-cross-referenced-equation-number-in-round-parentheses) or to [Reference appendix objects within texts as 'A. 1', but not 'Appendix A. 1'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413002/reference-appendix-objects-within-texts-as-a-1-but-not-appendix-a-1)

```
\documentclass{article}
% real code:
% \usepackage{myconference}
% MWE code:

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}

\makeatletter
\def\@gobbledot\csname thesection\endcsname{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\@gobbledot}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\label{sec:first}
In Section~\ref{sec:first} the reference does not look good.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I didn't know LaTeX can gobble so many things :)

Comment: @Marijn: Well, using a `\def` and 'entities' other than `{}` as delimiters is Black Magic, of course ;-). Please note that you have to do the same trick for `\p@subsection` etc. as well if needed, but with another definition of say `\@gobblesubsecdot` etc.